# Rails - What is the design pattern to subclass a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I have a model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Item has a property 'store'

Based on the value of store, I'd like the Item object to have different behaviour for specific methods.

Is there a common design pattern for this in Rails? How is this done cleanly without a big if-else statement in the methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually through [Single-Table Inheritance](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/).